# why am i getting this error when i try to req.logout()?

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies

**Error which i am getting:**

Error: req#logout requires a callback function

**My code:**

```
// @desc Logout User
// @rote GET /auth/logout
router.get("/logout", (req, res)=>{
    req.logout()
    res.redirect("/")
})
```

Comment: Upgrading Passport to 0.6.0 will require applications to pass a callback to req#logout

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/902#issuecomment-1133897569

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a change introduced in recent release. You can find it here in detail https://medium.com/passportjs/fixing-session-fixation-b2b68619c51d

From the documentation https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/authentication/logout/

try below code

```
router.get("/logout", function(req, res, next) {
  req.logout(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.redirect("/");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

req.logout() is an asynchronous function (it was not this way before, they only introduced this change recently for security reasons), and your current code is synchronous, which is why you get this error.

You can fix this error by modofying your code as follows:

```
app.post('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
    req.logout(function(err) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh okay, got it! It worked now. Thank you so much ❤
Yeah. before my req.logout() there was no callback. now it works 